# Unit test only asserting mock calls

Tags: php, oop, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

While refactoring my code base I found a piece of code which I'd like to extract into a separate class.

It will serve thumbnails for user profile pictures. The class (let's name it `UserImageManager`) will hold an instance of `UserMapper` and an instance of  `ImageRenderer`.

Now I do have a method for retrieving the cached url for a users profile picture. This method retrieves a `User` object from the `UserMapper` and triggers the `render` method of  `ImageRenderer` with the image path stored in the `User` object.

I wrote a test for this tiny function, mocking out the `ImageRenderer` and now I do not have a single assertion in this test case. It would not make any sense to assert the return value of the function, because it returns the cache file path, which is returned by the mocked `ImageRenderer`.

Now my question is: is it still a valid unit test, even with no assertions? Or how should I rewrite my test, not only checking calls to mock objects?

```
// The unit test
public function renderImageWillReturnCacheImagePath() {
  $this->_userImageManager->setImage(
    // Returns the ImageRenderer mock
    $this->_getImageMock(BASE_PATH . 'uploads/2012-06-06-wegmeister-91792.png', false, false)
  );

  // Invokes the function
  $image = $this->_userImageManager->render('wegmeister');
}

// The method to be tested
public function render($username, $width = false, $height = false) {
  $user = $this->_userMapper->getUserByUsername($username);

  if($user !== false && trim($user->getImage()) !== '') {
    $srcImage = $this->_folderUserImages . $user->getImage();
  }
  else {
    $srcImage = $this->_placeholderUserImage;
  }

  $dstImage = $this->_image->render($srcImage, 'jpg', $width, $height);
  if ($dstImage === false || empty($dstImage)) {
    throw new UnexpectedValueException('ImageRenderingFailed');
  }

  return $dstImage;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A test with no assertion is an incomplete test.

If you can't imagine what and how to assert, I'd say it means that the outcome of the method (unit) you want to test is undefined.

As you have not shown any specification nor told which type that function returns, the only thing I could imagine that you can test is if the exeception is thrown when needed.

Additionally it looks like that that method does too much and is too complex. So I would invest the time not in creating tests but to refactor the classes.

In the future you should write tests before you write the code, so you don't come into this situation.

Comment: basically .. if you do not know, what is the **correct** result, there is no way to test it.

Comment: Well you still can run a test and see if it executes w/o crashing. Like with fuzz-testing.

Comment: First: thanks for the answer. And after thinking about my design, I thought about dropping this code. It mainly does nothing but getting a  `User` object and passing the path to the users profile picture to the renderer (which itself just scales down the image and returns the path to the cached file). This is something which I could/should do in the controller.

Comment: Right, this would be more integration testing than unit-testing. But I didn't want to drop that term as well in the answer. You might also want to learn to prevent using `if`s all over the place: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc